# Showing that $\inf\left|x-p\right|$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, supremum-and-infimum

Let $X\subset R$ be non-empty. $f :\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ is defined by $$f(p)=\inf_{x\in X}\left|x-p\right|$$ for every $p\in\Bbb{R}$. How do I show that $f$ is continuous?

I tried using the reverse triangle inequality and the inequality $\inf\left|x-p\right|\leq\left|\inf (x-p)\right|$ to argue with $\epsilon-\delta$'s but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** You should be able to prove the inequality $|f(p)-f(q)|\le|p-q|$. Due to the symmetry, it is enough to show $f(p)-f(q)\le|p-q|$, or equivalently $f(p)\le f(q)+|p-q|$.

Comment: I can't prove it :(

Comment: @rat You need to employ the definition of infimum. Can you see why the final inequality in my answer is equivalent to $f(p)\le|x-q|+|p-q|$ for all $x\in X$?

Comment: If $f(p)\le f(q)+|p-q|$, then $f(p)\le |x-q|+|p-q|$ for sure but I can't see why the converse holds.

Comment: @rat If $a>f(q)$ then there is some $x\in X$ with $|x-q|<a$. Then $|x-p|<a+|p-q|$, and of course $f(p)\le |x-p|$ … I skipped some detail, but does this help?

Comment: As I take it by the triangle inequality we have $|x-p|\leq|x-q|+|p-q|$ for all $x\in X$. Taking the infimum of both sides we get $f(p)\leq f(q)+|p-q|$.

Comment: @rat You got it!